# Passing "This", but not really

Tags: java, android

So i am developing an Android application as a side project/hobby and I have come across the situation that I have to pass an Activity into a method for use a context (Don't question it)

The problem here is that I have to pass it into a PreferenceOnClickListener and so I am unable to use `this`. I have come up with the following code snippet, that you all might just wanna stab me for writing... Sorry, I feel bad for creating this as well:

```
Preference rebuildDB = pf.findPreference(getString(R.string.preference_rebuildDatabase));
    Activity thisContext = this;
    rebuildDB.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            SongLoader.generateXml(thisContext);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The thing I don't like is setting `thisContext` to the value of `this`, so my question is the following:

*Is this really as bad as I think it is, and is there any better way to achive it?*

Comment: As written, this is more of a Stack Overflow question:  I have this problem and how do I solve it?  Of course, this particular question would be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/56974/6660678).

Comment: @mdfst13 I disagree. This question has working code (not all the code required to run it but that's not a requirement), it's not example code in my opinion, it just asks for a specific refactoring - In my opinion this is not off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually can do is to refer to `YourActivityClassName.this`.

Java keeps the reference to the outer class' `this` within anonymous inner classes and allows you to reference them using `YourActivityClassName.this`

```
Preference rebuildDB = pf.findPreference(getString(R.string.preference_rebuildDatabase));
rebuildDB.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        SongLoader.generateXml(YourActivityClassName.this);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 way.

The first is by implementing the interface on your main class, so you don't have to create an anonymous class on the fly but just pass your *this*.

**UPDATE**

Here is an example on how to do it:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
                        implements Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {


        // You implement the listener method in your main 
        // class, so you just pass the current this object
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
           SongLoader.generateXml(this);
           return true;
        }

        // ... other code

       // when you record the listener your main class is the
       // listener now.
       rebuildDB.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);

}
```

The second is by creating a specific class that implement the interface.

This class is going to take in the constructor a parameter that is an instance of your main class.

So you will pass a new instance of this class instead of an instance of an anonymous class.

Here is an example of what I mean.

```
private static class MyOnPreferenceClickListener implements Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {

    MyActivity myActivity;

    public MyOnPreferenceClickListener(MyActivity myActivity) {
        this.myActivity = myActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        SongLoader.generateXml(myActivity);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I defined *private* and *static* considering to declare this class inside your main class.

**UPDATE**

The fist method is the quick and fast way, not considering the anonymous listener class, but could drive on very *fat* classes implementing many different listeners, depends on the Activity you're writing.

The second method, helps to decouple the listeners from your business code, and organize it in a better way.

Comment: I considered this, but it seemed a little overkill creating a nested class for the sole purpose of having `this` but if CR.SE thinks its alright, I will probably do it that way

Comment: I pointed 2 way. If for your purpose is better to have just one method, you could extend your main Activity class to implement the proper Listener interface. So you have to pass just *this* object to the listener method. I'll update this part too on my answer.

Comment: If you for some reason need multiple `Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener`, it is not an option to use `implements` on the activity. Using a separate `MyOnPreferenceClickListener` class for it can sometimes be preferable, but I would recommend to pass the activity as `Context` and declare the field `private final`.